# Probability that x is true given some amount of successful trials

Tags: probability

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this question: Suppose that I don't know if I am playing with a fair set of dice or not, but I know my probability of having the loaded dice is .38 if I roll doubles on the first try. Suppose I roll doubles 3 times in a row, what are my odds that I have the loaded dice. Suppose I roll doubles n times in a row, what are my odds? I know this isn't exactly a classic Binomial bistro, as that tells us our odds of x success in a row, rather than the odds of n being true after x successes.

Because I know the wording can be hard to interpret, suppose that if John is in a good mood on any given day there is a 0.38 probability he caught a fish the weekend before.  Suppose John is in a good mood 3-weekdays in a row.  What are the odds he caught a fish last weekend?

Comment: The problems don't sound the same, and the first one seems to  be lacking information.  What is the probability of throwing doubles with the loaded dice?

Comment: Sorry about that!  The probability of throwing doubles with the loaded dice is 0.657.  Basically my current thought is that our probability that the dice are loaded is (sum)k=0->n (0.38)(0.657)^k

Comment: Ok, so then you can use Bayes' to adjust your estimate of the probability based on the number of times you throw doubles.

Comment: Example;  say you throw doubles a second time.  Since you thought there was a $.38$ chance of having the loaded dice, the probability of getting doubles the second time is $.38\times .657+.62\times \frac 16=.353$, so your new estimate for the probability that you have the loaded dice is $\frac {.38\times .657}{.353}=.707$ and so on.

Comment: How do we set up Bayes' in this instance? P(Unfair|Doubles n times) = P(Doubles|Unfair)P(Unfair) / P(Doubles n times)?

Comment: I would do it recursively.  I showed you how to do it for two doubles in a row, just iterate that.

Comment: Thanks Lulu, I saw you added the probability for NOT having the loaded dice for the second roll - why is that?

Comment: There are two ways to get doubles.  Either you have the loaded dice and throw doubles or you have the fair dice and you throw doubles.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the known value $.38$ to work out what the apriori value for the probability that you had the loaded dice.  I get that as $.13456$ and you can know use that number to get a closed formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the indicator variable for the event "dice is loaded", and $Y$ for be the event "roll doubles on the first try".

You know that $P(X =1| Y_i=1) =0.38$

Now, you got the events $Y$ three times, for a given dice  - and I guess it's fair that the rolls are conditionally independent, i.e.:

$$P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3 | X) = P(Y_1| X)P(Y_2| X)P(Y_3| X)$$

Then
$$P(X|Y_1,Y_2,Y_3 ) = \alpha P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3 | X) P(X)=\alpha P(Y_1| X)P(Y_2| X)P(Y_3| X)$$

where $\alpha$ is a normalization factor that does not depend on $X$.

Then, if $Y_1=Y_2=Y_3$ 
$$
\begin{align}
P(X|Y_1,Y_2,Y_3 ) &= \alpha P(Y_1| X)^3 P(X)\\
&= \alpha \frac{P(X | Y_1)^3 P(Y_1)^3 }{P(X)^3} P(X)\\
&= \beta \frac{P(X | Y_1)^3 }{P(X)^2}
\end{align}
$$

where $$\beta^{-1}=\frac{P(X =1| Y_1)^3 }{P(X=1)^2}+\frac{(1-P(X =1| Y_1))^3 }{(1-P(X=1))^2}$$

In conclusion -as expected- you cannot say anything if you don't have an apriori probability for the loaded dice.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the a priori probability that you had the loaded dice was $p$.  Then Bayes would tell us that the revised probability after throwing doubles the first time was $$\frac {p\times .657}{p\times .657+(1-p)\times \frac 16}$$

As we know this is $.38$ we can solve for $p$ to get $$p=.13456$$

Now, assuming you throw doubles $n$ times in a row, Bayes says that the revised estimate for the probability is $$p_n=\frac {.13456\times .657^n}{.13456\times .657^n+(1-.13456)\times \frac 1{6^n}}$$